# Switch from View Controller to Tab Bar Controller in a Storyboard xCode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am working on an app in xCode 5.  This is a first at using the Storyboard. My app starts with a simple username/password login screen. Upon successful login, I want to programmatically switch from this login View to my Tab Bar Controller with the tab index set at 1.

I do not have a custom class for my UITabBarController. I can build one if need be.  Can someone help get me started or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Funny how typing out the question can help you solve it.  Here is the code I used in case someone has the same issue in the future

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *vc = (UITabBarController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UITabBarController"];

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    [vc release];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one **storyBoard** in your project then you can also use simply

```
self.storyboard
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to set your rootviewController to tabBarcontroller as soon as you authenticate the user. Here is how you can do this in swift.

```
let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
```

Where TabBarController is the storyboard id of your tab bar controller. It could be anything whatever name you have given it.

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard; drag a segue from your ViewControllers button (*or File's Owner to connect a method*) to your TabBarVC. Choose modal style and animation if you wish.

Add a new custom class for UITabBarController and assign it to TabBarVC in storyboard. 
In it's implementation file; put **self.selectedIndex = 1;**